# touch function in PHP 7 64-bit does not handle dates beyond 2038

Tags: php, year2038

On PHP 7.2.14 **64-bit**, on Windows, `touch()` cannot set a file's date to a date after 2038.  `filemtime()` will read such a file's date fine (date was set with an external tool).

Is this expected behavior?
Is it possible to write code that changes a file's date in a Y2038 friendly way?
Issue doesn't seem to be in PHP Bug Tracking : [Search for "2038"](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&search_for=%222038%22&x=0&y=0)

Code sample:

```
$filename = 'C:\\Test\\File.txt';
for ($i = 2035; $i <= 2040; $i++) {
    $t = mktime(1,1,1,1,1,$i);
    echo 'Date: '.date('D, d M Y H:i:s', $t).'<br>';
    touch($filename, $t);
    clearstatcache(true, $filename);
    $file = filemtime ($filename);
    echo 'File: '.date('D, d M Y H:i:s', $file).'<br><br>';
}
```

Ouput:

```
Date: Mon, 01 Jan 2035 01:01:01
File: Mon, 01 Jan 2035 01:01:01

Date: Tue, 01 Jan 2036 01:01:01
File: Tue, 01 Jan 2036 01:01:01

Date: Thu, 01 Jan 2037 01:01:01
File: Thu, 01 Jan 2037 01:01:01

Date: Fri, 01 Jan 2038 01:01:01
File: Fri, 01 Jan 2038 01:01:01

Date: Sat, 01 Jan 2039 01:01:01
File: Tue, 25 Nov 1902 18:32:45  <-- Wrong

Date: Sun, 01 Jan 2040 01:01:01
File: Wed, 25 Nov 1903 18:32:45  <-- Wrong
```

If I manually set the same file's date to 2040, the following works as expected:

```
$file = filemtime ('C:\\Test\\File.txt');
echo 'File: '.date('D, d M Y H:i:s', $file);
```

Output:

```
Date: Sun, 01 Jan 2040 01:01:01
```

Comment: Smells like it may be a bug but have you searched [PHP bugs](https://bugs.php.net/) to see if it has already been reported? Please [edit] your question and include your OS as well as the version of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported it as a bug in PHP and it was fixed the next day!

[Bug #78241](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78241) is fixed starting with PHP [7.3.8](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.3.8) & [7.2.21](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.21).

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you run into Year 2038 problem, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem
You cannot encode times after 03:14:07 UTC on 19 of January 2038, so you fall back to 13th of December 1901

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm testing.  64-bit version of PHP is able to handle these dates (as stated, `filemtime`, among others, does).  I'm wondering why `touch()` doesn't.